Delphi TMediaPlayer cannot play a WAV file?
I am using Delphi's TMediaPlayer to play .WAV files. It works on some files. However, when using it to play one .WAV files, in the following command:
    MediaPlayer.FileName := OpenDialog.FileName;
    MediaPlayer.Open;

it will raise an exception in Vcl.MPlayer:
    raise EMCIDeviceError.Create(ErrorMessage)

with the error message:

No WAV device installed...

But my Windows Media Player on the same computer can play it without any problems.
Below is the format info for the file that can be played via TMediaPlayer:

m_wAudioFormat    1       unsigned short
m_wNumChannels    1       unsigned short
m_dwSampleRate    8000    unsigned long
m_dwByteRate      8000    unsigned long
m_wBlockAlign     1       unsigned short
m_wBitsPerSample  8       unsigned short


And below the one that cannot be played:

m_wAudioFormat    1       unsigned short
m_wNumChannels    4       unsigned short
m_dwSampleRate    16000   unsigned long
m_dwByteRate      128000  unsigned long
m_wBlockAlign     8       unsigned short
m_wBitsPerSample  16      unsigned short


Update:
After the exception occurs, I check MediaPlayer.error and it is 326(MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSUNSUITABLE).

"PCM" is too broad - it could still have a different sample rate or bit depth (or channel count). Look at both file's format details to spot differences - you can use MPC-HC or directly MediaInfo. Likewise try to cut your large file into a small one and play that to see if its size was really the issue.

@AmigoJack, you are correct. I cut the large file into a small one and TMediaPlayer still cannot play it. I have put the formats for the playable and unplayable WAV file in the post.

Are both RIFF at all or is one of them RF64? WMP alone is by far not the best player, and TMediaPlayer is even worse - there's no guarantee it can handle everything.

@AmigoJack, both has RIFF in its header

I suppose that's MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSUNSUITABLE. Even if you'd be able to get the ancient Multimedia control panel in your Windows installation (I don't find it in Win7) I wouldn't know from where to get an additional (device or codec) driver to be installed which can process all flavors of WAV files. MCI is dead.

Your file has 4 channels. Do you want to play them all simultaneously or do you only want to play one of them (or something else)?

@AndreasRejbrand, I think  play one channel is enough. I just nee to let someone hear what the WAV file is, do not need great effect on the sound.

@alancc: But if the audio is an interview with one host and two interviewees, then maybe Ch 1 is the host, Ch 2 the first interviewee, Ch 3 the second interviewee, and Ch 4 music or video track sounds. If you only play one of the channels (Ch 2, say), the interview will become nearly incomprehensible.

In any case, I suspect that if you merge the wave to a single channel (so that the sample at each time is (a + b+ c+ d)/4, where a, b, c, and d are the samples of each channel), so you get a one-channel WAV file, then that file will play just fine.

@AmigoJack But why the MediaPlayer on the same computer can play it. The Audacity on the same computer can also open and convert it to MP3.

@AndreasRejbrand Is there a way to NOT pre-process the .WAV file, but let TMediaPlayer to be able to play the WAV? Because in the real situation, we cannot preprocess the .WAV file as it is selected by the end user.

"the MediaPlayer" and MCI/TMediaPlayer are two different softwares - they have almost nothing in common.

@AmigoJack, in your comment, you suggest to install a device driver, which is normally used for hardware devices and can shared by different software products, such as MediaPlayer and TMediaPlayer?

You ask as if you haven't read one of all the websites I've linked to. See all the blue underlined text? Those are links to click onto. Give up - you're lucky enough that Windows still supports MCI, hence TMediaPlayer being able to play anything at all. It won't magically work if you just keep asking. "Media Player" might have used MCI for the last time in Windows 3.0.

Hi, forget about TMediaplayer, it is old and deprecated. I use NewAc with great success in my projects.

FYI, TMediaPlayer has public Error and ErrorMessage properties. When the opened failed, Error would contain the MCI error code.

@RemyLebeau, The error code is 326(MCIERR_WAVE_OUTPUTSUNSUITABLE)
